# How to create a new user and assign READ only access permission in neo4j-version 3.2

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I have been trying to create a new user in neo4j database and trying to assign different roles to it .

I have created a new user using below query:-

**dbms.security.createUser("username", "password", true/false)**

I have also found that neo4j has provided by-default user access roles like reader , architect , developer etc. but this is giving me an error .

So far I created a user but it is having all accesses (Read/Write).

How can I create a new user and assign a READ only access to it. 
Consider I logged in as admin and I am using neo4j version 3.2 .

All suggestions and comments are welcome .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you using the community edition perhaps ? Role-based security is an Enterprise Edition feature ...

Comment: The third argument should also be a boolean and not the string "true/false".

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I am using community edition . Do we have any other feature to fulfill my requirement in community edition .

Comment: Yes.. third argument is Boolean.. My bad..

Comment: You could turn the complete database into read only (dbms.read_only=true) ... but other than that you are talking about Enterprise Edition features.

Comment: I have application running on python , which talks / inserts a data into neo4j . I can not turn complete database into read only .

Answer (score 0):

short answer will be

```
:use system
CREATE USER adam SET PASSWORD $password;
GRANT ROLE reader to adam;
```

**but** it only works in case you have **Enterprise Edition**

because even if you tried to created it your self using `GRANT` and `revoke`
to give him some access and take some . it will not works and you will get an error .

here is the code to create user that can only read and interact like the role `reader` in default roles .

```
CREATE ROLE Client
"GRANT ACCESS ON DATABASE * TO `Client`"
"GRANT MATCH {*} ON GRAPH * NODE * TO `Client`"
"GRANT MATCH {*} ON GRAPH * RELATIONSHIP * TO `Client`"
"GRANT SHOW CONSTRAINT ON DATABASE * TO `Client`"
"GRANT SHOW INDEX ON DATABASE * TO `Client`"
```